# How do I plot functions involving integration in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a characteristic function `CF(t, param1, param2, ...)` available (here `param`s are parameters of some distribution and are considered fixed). I want to use [Gil-Pelaez formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas) to obtain the CDF instead, so I wrote the following:

```
function [ F ] = CDF( x, param1, param2, ... )

integrand = @(v) imag(exp(-1i.*v.*x) .* CF(t, param1, param2, ...)) ./ v;
F = 0.5 - (1./pi) .* integral(integrand, 0, 100);

end
```

This works for single value, e.g. `CDF(0.1, param1, param2, ...)` gives me desired result. Now I want to plot `CDF` against a range of `x`, so I did

```
x = linspace(-1,1,100);
y = CDF(x, param1, param2, ...)
plot(x, y)
```

and I end up with the errors like these:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

But `y = CDF(x, param1, param2, ...)` does work, so the culprit seems to be the `exp(-1i.*v.*x)` part of the integrand, as the size of `v` and `x` does not match. But I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have guessed it right that the sizes of v and x don't match which is causing the error. `integral` passes vector values to the function handle to speed up computations by calculating function values for multiple points at once.

But in this case you should set the parameter `'ArrayValued'` to `true` in the call to integral in the CDF function. This would force integral to pass scalar values of v to the function handle and then CDF would be able to return vector valued `y` for vector valued `x`